# Hacked — got an IPv6 address, need hostname

Tags: dns, ping, ipv6, hostname

So I've got a problem... A few days ago I got hacked; someone logged on to an account of mine. So after a few clicks, 
I managed to get the IP Address: 2a02:a03f:1043:8500:75eb:6b9f:a26:8733

It's an IPV6 address; I don't care to post it here — it's not mine. So what I want to do: get the hostname of that IP address.
I can't `tracert` it, I can't `ping` it and the DNS lookup doesn't give a hostname.

I'm not going to do anything with the IP Address, but if I may get a hostname, it will be possible to know who did it, and confront them with the issue.

Comment: This is off topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omnomnom,
You can try https://enc.com.au/itools/inet6num to get the hostname of ipv4/6